# Android FileProvider: Can't use ContentResolver to fetch file?

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

From an outside app I want to do this to access a file on a FileProvider's internal storage:

```
InputStream inputStream=contentResolver.openInputStream(Uri.parse("content://com.example.android.fileprovider/path/to/file.txt"));
```

`android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"` is my Authority String as specified in other (FileProvider) app's manifest xml.

And:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="path" path="path/"/>
</paths>
```

The file exists in internal FP's storage under (files)/path/to/file.txt

But I always get IllegalArgumentException no root etc. Is this not how default Android FileProvider was intended to be used? Have I misunderstood its use? Why for instance in exported=false by default?

Comment: "But I always get IllegalArgumentException no root etc." -- please post an actual stack trace. "Why for instance in exported=false by default?" -- you are supposed to get the `Uri` handed to you by the app with the provider, where it also then grants you permission to the content at that `Uri`, such as via `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`.

Comment: Why should I get the Uri from the provider? I just want the ContentProvider to silently server request coming in from other apps on the device.

Comment: "Why should I get the Uri from the provider?" -- because the provider is not exported, and so the app with the provider needs to grant you temporary permission to each and every `Uri` that you intend to use. `FileProvider` is for situations like allowing a third-party app to handle `ACTION_VIEW` on an app's content.

Answer (score 0):

- First you have to replace your package name with
  android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
- secondly there is no directory exists with name "path" it must be
  something like image/, video/ etc in the file segment