# Use Content Provider to view a file which is in app A internal /data/data/com.example.com/files/a.txt be readable to in all apps

Tags: android, android-studio, android-contentprovider, android-fileprovider, android-internal-storage

I have an app A which has a file in /data/data/com.example.com/files/a.txt, Now I want that using content provider my app B can call that file from A internal directory I have seen implementations of SQLDB for a content provider where making provider exported and using contrast and content resolver its possible but I have not seen any such with a file is that possible.
Here in this training google has shown for SQLDB is that same possible for files

https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-practicals/en/Unit%204/111b_p_add_a_content_provider_to_wordlistsql.html

Comment: Considering I'm a beginner please pardon the mistakes in question

Comment: You can use a FileProvider to serve your txt file to any other app using ACTION_VIEW. The user can then select your app.

Comment: You should first tell how app B would know that there is somewhere a file belonging to app A.

Comment: App B is a part of App A so the app can get hardcoded value after creating content provider like content://authority/path  and if i use fileprovider then I will have to initiate the send action from App A but what i want is My App B on button press loads content from App A internal file to my textview

Comment: Its like From an outside app I want to do this to access a file on a FileProvider's internal storage

Comment: `App B is a part of App A ` ??? How would that go? Then it is one app. I dont understand at all.

Comment: If App B is part of app A then it could use that file path directly. No need for a file provider or content provider. Please explain better.

Comment: If app B should load a file it should know an uri. How does it know that uri? And how did it get read/write permission to use it?

Comment: My question is similar to this one as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36942917/android-fileprovider-cant-use-contentresolver-to-fetch-file  but here as beginner i have not seen any implementation to do it so asked

Comment: can i contact u directly on twitter linkedin etc anyplace for better clarification?

Comment: App A should export its file provider you can read in that thread. After that app B can setup the uri. Maybe its true. I never tried.